What to use to fill shower head plate gaps?
What is the best material to use to fill the gaps in the plate of the shower head & tile? Caulk? Canned foam?


Any pieces of that tile left?  You will want to fill the hole with a matching piece of tile.  Will want two pieces with a half circle in the middle.

Sadly, no, I don't have access to any pieces of tile. Shower was tiled by previous owners. Any other solution?

The answer seems the best.  It is covering of the holes nicely, more than anything else that matters.  About the only thing else is to get a single tile that fits over and make a design statement.  A blue or red tile.  Single tiles are hard to come by.

Get an oversized escutcheon plate cover.

Or a  "decorative" flat plate that goes behind the escutcheon.
